# How could you hide/show a HTML element based off a PHP responce?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to make my websites more user friendly. I would like it so if the user types in a incorrect password, the HTML element `<div class="wrong password">` will show. This element should only show if my PHP script says the password is incorrect, otherwise it is hidden as if it did not exist. How could I go about doing this? HTML is a very static language. My first thought is I need to use javascript but I am not sure how to go about this.

Consider the code:

```
  <?php
  session_start();

  //Authenticate user

  //Wrong password!

?>

<body>

  <div class="paper">
    <h3>Login</h3>
    <div class="wrongpassword"><p>Your password is incorrect</p></div>
    <form action="login.php" method="post" enctype="multi-part/form-data">
      Username:<br>
      <input placeholder="Username" name="username" type="text" autofocus><br>
      Password:<br>
      <input placeholder="Password" name="password" type="password"><br>
      <br>
      <input name="login" type="submit" value="login">
    </form>
    <hr>
    <p>Need a account? <a href="register.php">Sign up here!</a></p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP began as a template language. You can open PHP tags in the middle of your markup and conditionally add HTML to your document.

Try this - assuming you're using the inbuilt [password hashing](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php) functions in PHP:

```
<?php 
if (!password_verify($password, $hash)) {
     echo '<div class="wrongpassword"><p>Your password is incorrect</p></div>';
}
?>
```

Comment: I'm just wondering why you think you would need a separate `<div>`-container for something like this. The `<p>` is already block-level, and you can throw any class on that as well, to style it properly.

Answer (score 1):

This should give you a good start.

Basically what you want to do is first check to see that the form was submitted.

Once you know the form was submitted, then you want to check and see if the password is correct. If the password is incorrect, you change the value of the variable `$error` to true.

Then when the page is rendering, the if statement surrounding the Password Error will either be rendered or skipped depending on the value of `$error`

```html
<?php
  session_start();

  $error = false;
  
  // if the form has been posted
  if ($_POST) {
    //Authenticate user

    // do db query and get users password

    if ($_POST['password'] == $password) {
      // success
      // redirect user to next page
    } else {
      $error = true;
    }
  }

?>

  <body>

    <div class="paper">
      <h3>Login</h3>
      <?php if ($error): ?>
        <div class="wrongpassword">
          <p>Your password is incorrect</p>
        </div>
      <?php endif; ?>
      <form action="login.php" method="post" enctype="multi-part/form-data">
        Username:<br>
        <input placeholder="Username" name="username" type="text" autofocus><br> Password:
        <br>
        <input placeholder="Password" name="password" type="password"><br>
        <br>
        <input name="login" type="submit" value="login">
      </form>
      <hr>
      <p>Need a account? <a href="register.php">Sign up here!</a></p>
    </div>
  </body>
```